# How to convert a `List[IO[Unit]]` into `Stream[IO,Unit]`

Tags: scala, scala-cats, fs2, cats-effect

I have a `List[IO[Unit]]` which consists of distinct works encoded in `IO`. I would like to convert it into `Stream[IO,Unit]`

Currently, what I have done is this

```
val works: List[IO[Unit]]
works.map(work => Stream.eval(work)).reduceLeft((left, right) => left ++ right)
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest doing one of those:

```scala
Stream.emits(works).flatMap(Stream.eval) // or
Stream.emits(works).evalMap(x => x) // which is the same, or
Stream(works: _*).evalMap(x => x) // which is also the same
```

There's a difference vs. doing `Stream.evals` on a `works.sequence` in that you lose the fact that your effect is made of different parts. That will surface itself if you run stream partially, e.g. by doing:

```scala
stream.take(3).compile.drain
```

If you *do not* sequence, it will only run first 3 elements from `works`. If you do, it will run all of them.

From other options proposed by Luis Miguel, only the `unfoldEval` one preserves the separation, but it's probably an overkill.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that `sequence` would combine all works into one. Thanks for mentioning and providing a better solution.

Answer (score 3):

I can think of these three alternatives:
*(Note, I just checked they typecheck but I didn't run them)*

```
def stream1: Stream[IO, Unit] =
  Stream.evalSeq(works.sequence)

def stream2: Stream[IO, Unit] =
  Stream.evals(works.sequence)

def stream3: Stream[IO, Unit] =
  Stream.unfoldEval(works) {
    case work :: tail =>
      work.map { io =>
        Some(io -> tail)
      }

    case Nil =>
      IO.pure(None)
  }
```

BTW, if you got that **List[IO[Unit]]** after a `map`.

You can `data.traverse(f)` instead of `works.map(f).sequence`
And `f(input).map { io =>` instead of `work.map { io =>`